# how can we implement crop functionality as android lollipop 5.1.1?

Tags: android, crop

I am developing an application which included crop functionality.

and my requirement is want to implement crop functionality as in android lollipop 5.1.1. is it possible? i tried and googled also but no use. is any one have idea. please help me..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you mean default gallery or photo crop?

Comment: ya.. like gallery/photo crop..